# how to pass pointers to a function in C

Tags: c

What I want to do is to put DLLname where DLLnameHERE.dll is.

This is a piece of my code:

```
int ToLoadLibrary(char * DLLname) 
{

HINSTANCE hinstLib;
MYPROC ProcAdd;
BOOL fFreeResult, fRunTimeLinkSuccess = FALSE;

// Get a handle to our DLL module created in the previous example. Make sure you already copied the mydllpro.lib and mydllpro.dll to the appropriate folders...
hinstLib = LoadLibrary(L"DLLnameHERE.dll");
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Have you looked at using [strncat](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strncat)?

Comment: Then do it. People here wont do your work for you. If you have a question, ask and show what you have attempted. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem you run into is a Microsoft-specific one. The macro `LoadLibrary` expands, depending on preprocessor macros, either to the name of a function that accepts a `char const*` or a `wchar_t const *`. In your case, the call

```
hinstLib = LoadLibrary(L"DLLnameHERE.dll");
```

suggests that the latter is the case.

The easiest way around this problem is to use the name of the function that accepts `char const *` directly; it is `LoadLibraryA`:

```
hinstLib = LoadLibraryA(DLLname);
```

The mechanism is described in greater detail [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c426s321.aspx) in the MSDN.